# How can i display in real time in pictureBox1 each time an image have been saved to the hard disk?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a new form i added to my project: I called the new form Images.cs
In the new Form constructor i'm calling a method called Test:

```
public Images()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Test();
        }
```

And this is the Test method:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"e:\test.bmp");
Bitmap bmp1 = ImageTrim.ImagesTrim(bmp);
bmp1.Save(@"e:\Image\image" + imagescount.ToString() + ".bmp",                              System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
bmp1.Dispose();
bmp.Dispose();
filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"e:\Image\", "*.bmp");
Bitmap newbmp = new Bitmap(filePaths[0]);
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
f1.bmptoshow = newbmp;
Form1.pb1.Image = newbmp;
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
f1.bmptoshow = newbmp;
newbmp.Dispose();
imagescount++;
```

The variable imagescount is a global int.

The variable filePaths is string[] and also i made it global and also public.

In this case filePaths contain 2 items.

I want to pass the first item a bmp image file to Form1 pictureBox1 and display the bmp file in the Form1 pictureBox1.

In form1 what i did:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace WebBrowserScreenshots.cs
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static PictureBox pb1 = new PictureBox();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            pictureBox1.Image = pb1.Image;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WebBrowserScreenshots wbss = new WebBrowserScreenshots();

        }

        public Bitmap bmptoshow
        {
            set
            {
                this.pictureBox1.Image = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Either using the bmptoshow in Form1 or the public static in Form1 pb1 dosen't show anything on the pictureBox1 in Form1.

Comment: 1) Are the images saved as expected? 2) Where do you call the BackgroundWorker? 3) Where do you call Test() ?  In the BW?

Answer (score 0):

So, once an image is saved, you want to show that image in your PictureBox? Off my head you can implement this:

```
public void imageSaved(){

if(File.exists(//Whatever your file name is, to check it actually saved){
PictureBox1.image = //Image location
}
else{
MessageBox.show("Image didnt save!");
}
}
```